# Action não Executa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autenticação, federation-authentication

Estou usando autenticação por STS, e dado determinada configuração no `web.config`
não consigo fazer com que minha action (Sign In) execute o que deveria.

para ilustar segue codigo:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class SegurancaController : SecurityController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
....
        }

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult IndexPost()
        {
....
        }
    }
```

SecurityController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult SignIn(string issuer)
        {
            var wSFederationAuthenticationModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
            string str = null;
            if (!base.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                str =
                    new SignInRequestMessage(new Uri(string.IsNullOrEmpty(issuer) ? wSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer : issuer),
                        wSFederationAuthenticationModule.Realm, wSFederationAuthenticationModule.Reply).WriteQueryString();
            }
            return new RedirectResult(str ?? wSFederationAuthenticationModule.Reply);
        }
```

E Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Seguranca" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="2880"  defaultUrl="~/home" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

NOTA: Se as tags `<authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>` forem comentadas eu consigo executar a URL normalmante... mas perco a verificação se o usuário estiver logado.

Comment: O que eu fico FUDID* é que os caras ao invés de participar, sai por ai dando downvote...

Comment: E não é só você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não consegui resolver, Solucionei o caso com outra forma.

Adicionei um Handler para interceptar as requisições da seguinte forma.

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            var isAuthenticate = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            if (!isAuthenticate && controller != "Seguranca")
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary 
                    { 
                        { "controller", "Seguranca" }, 
                        { "action", "Index" } 
                    });
        }
    }
```